# before_save assign a hash of attributes activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i want to change some value in before_save callback. normally I see people do this:

```
def this_is_a_callback
  self.attr1 = 'xxx'
  self.attr2 = 'yyy'
end
```

I have it in form of { attr1: 'xxx', attr2 = 'yyy' }, how should I inject them to the model?

I tried assign_attributes and self.attributes= but they somehow have stack level too deep problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried assign_attributes and self.attributes= but they somehow have
> stack level too deep problem.

Look for existing callbacks that are being triggered by these assignments. Likely there is a circular reference there. If just reading the code doesn't work

- Look closely for other callbacks in the error backtrace array.
- See [the "Debugging callbacks" section in the ActiveRecord::Callbacks documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Examine the callbacks returned by `MyModel._save_callbacks` to see if they are what you expect. Check each for recursions, e.g. by commenting them out.

Comment: thx, seems some problem with globalize gem, i updated the gem and it worked